# Java Inventory - ADT class & File Input troubles

Tags: java, filereader

I've hit a roadblock with this program.

I have a program that involves creating a program that involves the "inventory" of Cadillac, and among all else, I cannot find answers to my questions.

I just do not know what to do. I'll provide the directions and then post the syntax I have so far.

Here is what I have to do:

- inventory for a fictional Cadillac Dealership and allows the inventory to be searched to display a list of cars that meet specific criteria.
- create an ADT class called Cadillac which contains four fields of instance data: Strings for model name, stock number and color, and an integer for price. The class contains one Constructor, which receives values for all four instance fields, and assigns the parameter values to the instance variables. The class also contains a simple accessor method and mutator method for each field of instance data.
- When the program is ran, it loads the inventory from a file, "inventory.dat".
- Here is a sample of the contents of the file:
  DTS 11210 Glacier White 42706
  Escalade 66502 Crimson Pearl 65547
  XLR 58362 Radiant Bronze 78840
  SRX 16218 Radiant Bronze 44522
- Each line (each record) contains 4 fields of data: strings for model name, a 5–digit stock number, and color, and an integer for price. The delimiter between the fields is a tab character (“\t”).
- In main(), create an array of Cadillac objects, read in a record from the file, split it into its 4 fields, create a Cadillac object and add it to the array.
- the inventory file changes and your program needs to work no matter how many records are in the file. You are guaranteed there will never be more than 100 records in the file (they only have room for 100 cars on the lot), and that each record will contain exactly 4 fields of valid data.
- The user can search the inventory two ways: by model name and by price. After you load the inventory, ask the user which search they want to do. If they indicate “by model name”, have them enter the name to search for. The valid model names are: DTS, Escalade, ESV, EXT, SRX, STS, and XLR. Search the inventory for all cars with that name and display a table of results on the console screen.

-When the user indicates he/she wants to search by price, have them enter the price to search
for, then perform the search, displaying all cars that have a price within $3,000 of the search
price. 
- The program should loop to do as many searches as the user wants. Let the user end the
program by clicking a “Cancel” button when asked for the type of search they want to perform.
A “Cancel” button on the second question (the model or price to search for) should not end the
program, but your code should recognize it as an invalid entry, and not throw an exception.
Besides the list output, all input and output in the program should be with JOptionPane dialogs.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Inventory {

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
    String line;
    String[] fields;
    String[] items;
    int count = 0;
    int recCount;
    Cadillac[] list = new Cadillac[100];

    try
    {
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( "inventory.dat" ) );
      line = br.readLine();
      while( line != null )
      {
        fields = line.split( "\t" );
        items[count++] = new Cadillac( fields[0], fields[1], fields[2],
                                                fields[3] );
        line = br.readLine();
      }
      br.close();
    }
    catch( IOException e )
    {
      System.out.println( "Can't open input file. Program terminating." );
      System.exit( 1 );
    }

    }
    public static int loadArray(Cadillac[] items)
    {


    }

}

class Cadillac {
                    //Instance data
    private String model;
    private String stockNum;
    private String color;
    private int price;
                    //Constructor
    public Cadillac(String mdl, String stckNum, String clr, int prc)
    {
        model = mdl;
        stockNum = stckNum;
        color = clr;
        price = prc;
    }
                    //Set of Accessor and Mutator Methods
    public String getModel(){
        return model;
    }
    public void setModel(String newModel){
        model = newModel;
    }
    public String getStockNum(){
        return stockNum;
    }
    public void setStockNum(String newStockNum){
        stockNum = newStockNum;
    }
    public String getColor(){
        return color;
    }
    public void setColor(String newColor){
        color = newColor;
    }
    public int getPrice(){
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(int newPrice){
        price = newPrice;
    }
}
```

PLEASE HELP! I do not have any other idea of what to do.

Comment: What part of this homework in particular are you having a problem with? If you are encountering an error you need to include it in your question. Try to be direct and to the point in order to help others help you.

Comment: It is saying that it cannot find the symbol constructor Cadillac, which I have tried everything to my knowledge to help fix it, but nothing is working. On top of that, I am generally just at a loss of what to do to complete this assignment.  I know that having others code out homework is something that should not be done and is looked down upon, but this is just something I'm truly struggling with and need almost an elementary walkthrough as to how to go about writing this program.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your comment:

> It is saying that it cannot find the symbol constructor Cadillac

Your only constructor defined for Cadillac has parameters `(String, String, String, int)` but when you try to instantiate the object in main, you pass it four Strings. Java is throwing an error because it can't find the correct constructor.

Either pass the last parameter as an int or create a new constructor for your arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Your most immediate problem is that the signature of your data objects constructor is incompatible with the way you are calling it. You have declared your constructor as so:

```
public Cadillac(String mdl, String stckNum, String clr, int prc)
```

It takes three string arguments and an int, but you are calling it with four strings:

```
new Cadillac( fields[0], fields[1], fields[2], fields[3] );
```

Thats the source of the compile error you reported seeing. You should convert your last String to an int.

```
new Cadillac( fields[0], fields[1], fields[2], Integer.parseInt(fields[3]).intValue() );
```

Apart from that there is another glaring error in your code. You declare an array of strings, but are attempting to store instances of 'Cadillac' into it:

```
String[] items;
// ...
items[count++] = new Cadillac( ... );
```

I won't code your entire homework for you, but my advise would be to first right down in plain English sentences, each task that needs to be accomplished in order to complete the overall program. Then start translating each individual sentence into code, ideally in the form of methods on your classes that can be called. As you run into issues, come back and ask ***specific*** questions and I'm sure there will be someone here willing to help you more.

Good luck.

Comment: Okay, I have looked into this some more, and I have come up with a more specific question. How would I go about creating an array of Cadillac objects, read the record from the "inventory.dat" file, split it into the four fields, and create a Cadillac object & add it to the array.  I'm just having a little trouble with that, but if I could get that, I should be able to get the rest.